# How can I use the test_proportion data in a machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, train-test-split

I have a data with 4000 CNN features and it is a binary classification problem. All I know about the test data is the proportions of 1 and 0. How can I tell to my model to predict test labels by using the proportions data ? (Like is there a way to say in order to reach this proportions I will give this instance 0.)

How can I use it to increase accuracy ? In my case the training data is mostly consist of 1 (85%) and 0(15%) 
However in my test data proportion of l is given as (%38) So it is much different than training data.

I worked a little bit with balancing the data and it helped. However my model still predicts 1 for nearly all of the data. It may occur because of the adaptation problem also.

As @birdwatch suggested I decrease the threshold for the 0 value and try to increase the 0 label count on the prediction.

```
# Predicting the Test set results 
y_pred = classifier.predict_proba(X_test) 
threshold=0.3 
y_pred [:,0] = (y_pred [:,0] < threshold).astype('int')
```

Before the number of classes were as in follows:

```
 1 :   8906
 0 :   2968
```

After changing threshold now it is

```
1 :  3221
0 :  8653
```

However is there any other way that I can use test_proportions which ensures the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any sensible way to that. Doing so would create a weird bias in the model. One thing you could do is accept the less likely outcome only is it has high enough score. Normally you'd use 0.5 threshold, but here you might take e.g. 0.7.

Comment: @Ege please notice that updating the question *after* a useful answer has been offered in a way that renders this answer irrelevant is not how SO works. I kindly suggest you accept the answer and open a new question with the new details (you can always include a link here, if necessary). More to the point, it is clear that the specific results you get now depend on the particular threshold choice, so you may want to do a little further experimenting, and include the outcomes in your *new* question. Include the term "class imbalance" or "imbalanced data", as well as the tag `imbalanced-data`.